# Problema com inserção de TIMER na tabela MySQL usando JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jdbc, timer

Fala pessoal!

Estou com o seguinte problema e estou buscando a melhor solução possível. O código a seguir ao ser executado um tempo é salvo na String tAtual(tempo atual) e enviado para o banco de dados para a coluna tempo. Esse tempo atual é atualizado a todo momento, portanto o próximo valor de tempo sobrescreverá o valor atual. Para corrigir isso criei uma nova coluna, chamada de tTotal (tempo total), onde a ideia é que ele faça a soma do tempo atual com o tempo anterior. Para isso eu preciso fazer uma query do tempo e somar com a string tAtual e assim fazer o Update da coluna tTotal do banco de dados. Porém como eu faço para somar duas Strings de tempo? ou dois Timers? Existe uma forma melhor de somar esses valores que faça uma query e update ao mesmo tempo?

```
 String tAtual = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", horas, minutos, segundos); //Esse é o tempo atual
    String sql = "UPDATE vagas SET tempo = (?) WHERE nomeID = (?)";

    try (PreparedStatement ps = Conecta.conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, tAtual);
        ps.setString(2, temp.getNome());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    //System.out.println(temp.getNome() + " levou " + tAtual);//salva e mostra o tempo atual

    String sql2 = ("SELECT tempo FROM vagas WHERE nomeID =(?)");

    Time tempo = null;
    try (PreparedStatement ps2 = Conecta.conn.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
        ps2.setString(1, temp.getNome());
        ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            tempo = rs.getTime("tempo");//fiz a query do tempo 
        }
    }

    //tTotal é a soma do tempo que já está no banco de dados com o tAtual    
    String sql3 = ("UPDATE vagas SET Ttotal = (?) WHERE nomeID = (?)");
    //String tTotal = tAtual + tempo; //Problema maior aqui
    try (PreparedStatement ps3 = Conecta.conn.prepareStatement(sql3)) {
        ps3.setString(1, tTotal);
        ps3.setString(2, temp.getNome());
        ps3.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar a [função](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) `ADDTIME` do MySQL:

```
UPDATE vagas set tempo = :tempo, ttotal = ADDTIME(ttotal, :tempo)
WHERE nomeID = :nomeID
```

Repare que estamos utilizando *named parameters*, que devem ser setados desta maneira:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = Conecta.conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString("tempo", tAtual);
    ps.setString("nomeID", temp.getNome());
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Excelente, só precisei alterar o "tempo" e o "nomeID" para valores do tipo int (que é o aceitável como parâmetro do setString) e na String fiz o uso da (?). Obrigado.